# What is the difference between the vasomotor center and cardiovascular center in the brain?

Tags: brain, neurology, cardiology, physiology

The vasomotor center is introduced as the following in our coursework:

> The vasomotor center is located bilaterally in the reticular substance of the medulla and lower third of pons. It contains the vasoconstrictor, vasodilator and sensory (Nucleus tractus solitarius)

However various other sources I have researched either make no note of a "Vasomotor Area" or simply attribute the effects of the vasomotor area (vasodilation and constriction) to a Cardiovascular center.

Furthermore they mention a cardioacceleratory area and a cardioinhibitory area, again there are conflicting sources where some say they are separate areas altogether and others say they are simply alternative names for the vasoconstrictor and vasodilator areas.

I am terribly confused, is the cardiovascular center the same thing as the vasomotor center (*and the vasodilator and vasoconstrictor areas the same as the cardioaccelaratory and cardioinhibitory areas*) or are they seperate entities? I would appreciate an explanation that clears my doubt and sources for further reading would be appreciated.

**Sources consulted:**

1. Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology
2. Elsevier’s Integrated Physiology
3. Human Physiology: From Cells to Systems Lauralee Sherwood
4. Paul Johns - Clinical Neuroscience-Churchill Livingstone (2014)

Comment: @anongoodnurse My apologies, I've removed my post from SE Biology.

Comment: Thank you! Removed my close vote.